# SlideShowServiceMethod not called from Web Service

Tags: asp.net, slideshow, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to use Image Slidshow on my Webform, and I have been implemented all required stuffs for to do that but still something is wrong here, I don't know exactly but here `GetSlides()` is not called for any reason.
Here is the `aspx` code

```html
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference path="~/SlideShow.asmx" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        
             <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server"
             Height="250px" Width="300px" ImageUrl="~/Images/Slide Show Startup/1.jpg"

             />
        
                
        <ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender1" runat="server"
            TargetControlID="img1"
            SlideShowServicePath ="SlideShow.asmx"
            SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides"
            AutoPlay="true"
            Loop="true" PlayInterval="500">

        </ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender>
```

and here is the `asmx` code:

```html
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="SlideShow" %>
 
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class SlideShow : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] Slides = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[2];
        
        Slides[0] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("Images/1.jpg", "One", "Description 1");
        Slides[1] = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide("Images/2.jpg", "Two", "Description 2");

        return Slides;
    }
}
```

All paths are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `static` keyword to make it work.

Comment: Do you able to see method list at SlideShow.asmx page?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Yes, But it's okay, I got another way, It's simplest way, here is the link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/ajax-slideshowextender-control/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link and easiest way to achieve this feature:
[www.c-sharpcorner.com article by Purushottam Rathore](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/ajax-slideshowextender-control/)